# GetFileAttributes returning FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE for nonexistent file

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using GetFileAttributes to check for existence before creating the file, and displaying a dialog to the user (standard "do you want to replace the existing file")

```
if (GetFileAttributes(szFilePath) != 0xffffffff) { /* display "do you want to replace?"*/}
```

Occasionally, it will return success for a file that *cannot* possibly exist, since the folder it would be in has *just* been created (using CreateDirectory).  When it does, the attributes it returns are simply FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE.

Any idea what's going on?

Edit: In response to the endless series of "you should use INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES instead" I have done so.

```
DWORD dwFile = GetFileAttributes(szFilePath);
if (dwFile != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) { /* display "do you want to replace?"*/}
```

I get the same result.  dwFile is returned as FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE for a file that does not exist.  I am quite sure it does not exist.  The folder was only just created.  I am not using GetTempFileName().  I can copy szFilePath from the debugger and visit the folder using both Explorer and the command line, with neither of them showing the file as existing.

Comment: You should use `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` rather than a magic number.

Comment: True.  However, that will still not equal FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE.

Comment: Why not just ignore the attributes and attempt to create the file and let it fail if it already exists? `CreateFile()` has a `CREATE_NEW` disposition for that exact purpose. It will report an `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` error if the file already exists. If the user agrees to overwrite, you can then create the file with a `CREATE_ALWAYS` disposition.

Comment: For this exact case that would work.  I just created the folder, so I do have write access.  But in the more general case, where I might want to know if a file exists and I don't have write access, CreateFile will fail regardless.  (admittedly with an Access Denied error in that example, which I could check for.)  In general, when an API call is returning nonsense, I would _really_ prefer to understand what is going on.  That way I'm much less likely to shoot myself in the foot with the misfiring gun later.

Comment: The function returns `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` on failure so you should be checking for that, not `0xffffffff`.  Not sure how you know what it's returning since you aren't saving the return value.

Comment: I know what it's returning by way of an attached debugger.  Also, using INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES instead of 0xffffffff does have the same result when tested.

Comment: @jbcarpen: `GetFileAttributes()` returns a `DWORD` and `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` is strongly typed as a `DWORD` and thus is not subject to sign-extension errors on 64bit, whereas a `0xffffffff` literal can be. `0x00000000ffffffff` is a very different value than `0xffffffffffffffff`.  A  `GetFileAttributes()` failure on 64bit returns `(DWORD)0xffffffff` which extends to `0x00000000ffffffff` (which matches `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` on both 32bit and 64bit) and not `0xffffffffffffffff`. Consider using `GetFileAttributesEx()` or `FindFirstFile()` instead to avoid that pitfall.

Comment: @jbcarpen: Also, are you *SURE* the file does not really exist?  How are you populating `szFilePath` exactly? For instance, if you are using `GetTempFileName()`, are you taking into account that it can create the file it generates a name for?

Comment: Any chance that optimization is messing up the debugger?  Just to be safe, have you tried saving the return value in a variable and, e.g., printing it?  Also, you could try setting the last error code to zero and checking the last error code when you hit the odd result - it shouldn't be set, but if it is, the value might give you a clue.

Comment: Also, try using Process Monitor (available for download from the MS web site) to see what is going on from the kernel's point of view.

Comment: optimization is disabled, so no, there's no chance it's messing up the debugger.  (same bug with and without optimization, easier to debug without.)

Comment: To be honest I do not believe this really happens. Can you write a MCVE that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: What does Process Monitor show?

Comment: Procmon shows CreateFile (with Desired Access: Read Attributes), QueryBasicInformationFile, CloseFile happening against the folder the file would be in if it existed.  all report SUCCESS.  A similar call to GetFileAttributes() with a file that correctly returns nonexistence shows only CreateFile (with Desired Access: Read Attributes) called against the file directly (instead of the folder), which reports NAME NOT FOUND.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, turns out this is a holdover from DOS.  The specific filename is important.
The following line of code will reproduce the issue, assuming that c:\aux.c doesn't exist on your system, and that you have a 'C' drive.  (My initial encounter with the behavior was deep in a tree, but this is a good minimal case.)

```
DWORD dwFile = GetFileAttributes(TEXT("C:\\aux.c"));
```

It's related to this question over on SuperUser
[Why does this file apparently not exist when attempting to delete it?](https://superuser.com/questions/554072/why-does-this-file-apparently-not-exist-when-attempting-to-delete-it)
There are certain filenames that are protected, even when the file doesn't actually exist, and has never existed.

CON, PRN, **AUX**, CLOCK$, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9 LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9.

These are all protected, and can cause problems if you run into a case where you are trying to edit/create/delete them on windows.

Comment: This is why you want to post a minimal complete and verifiable example. If your post had shown that you were trying to delete a file named `aux.c` someone could have pointed out the problem earlier.

Comment: This is question asking 101 right here. Show an MCVE. You were asked.

Comment: I was indeed asked.  However, I figured out the answer in the process of creating the MCVE.  So the request for one was itself quite helpful.